# Hide content when URL is less/more than X characters long

Tags: javascript

I have an html document of which I want to hide some ids (in this example, id="test") when the URL is less than 30 characters long.

```
var test = document.getElementById('test');
var l = location.href.length;
if(l<30){function hide1(){test.style.display="none";}};
```

Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but do you call `hide1()` somewhere in your code?

Comment: Nope. I guess I must stop naming my functions. It worked once for something and that has been my superstition ever since :P

Comment: That's a pretty easy mistake to make. Sometimes you just can't see this things in your own code, too, because you've looked at it too long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're declaring a function and not calling it. And you don't need it anyway.

Replace

```
if(l<30){function hide1(){test.style.display="none";}};
```

with

```
if(l<30) test.style.display="none";
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do something like this

```
function hideAnchorWithLengthLessThan (anchor, length) {
    if (anchor.href.length < length) {
        anchor.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

than you can do

```
var test = document.getElementById('test');
hideAnchorWithLengthLessThan(test, 30);
```